# Update a view - Is this a right approach for tabbarapplication?

Tags: ios, refresh, reload

The data  from a weather station  is saved into a Database. I am only interested in live data.Throug  web service i have these Data in XML format. and These values are updating every 30 seconds.
I want to give the user the possiblity  to refresh the values with a updateButton whenever he/she wants.

I made a method like below:

```
- (IBAction)buttonUpdate:(id)sender {

    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

It is working so far but is this the right way? Do Apple allow such a way?

What is the best approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-using `viewDidLoad` is not a good approach. Here is what you should do:

Take the code that loads this weather into the view and remove it from `viewDidLoad` and place it into something like

```
-(void)loadWeatherView {
    //Code Here
}
```

Then, in `viewDidLoad`, use `[self loadWeatherView];` to update the view when the app first loads it's view.

Then change buttonUpdate to:

```
- (IBAction)buttonUpdate:(id)sender {

    [self loadWeatherView];
}
```

Using `viewDidLoad` might not cause a problem, but usually you want to do more high-memory loading there that will NOT get altered very often. It will be called every time the view loads anyway, so constantly calling it from code is not the best idea. Now in this case it probably isn't terribly important, but just as a habit, I like to put as little actual code into `viewDidLoad` as possible, and instead just call the methods from `viewDidLoad`, that way you have access to loading individual things like I supplied above.

This makes it so you can update one thing instead of reloading stuff that does not require re-loading.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a "viewDidLoad" method is bad style. You should create a new method [self updateData] and invoke that instead. Put all the functionality relevant to the update itself in there and it should work better.